# Column not found with CTE query on H2

Tags: sql, h2, common-table-expression

I am trying to understand how cte works but can't solve column not found error.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NODE (UUID VARCHAR NOT NULL, PARENT_UUID VARCHAR NULL,
NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (UUID));
```

This is my query:

```
WITH tree AS
(
    -- Anchor member
    SELECT * FROM node WHERE uuid = ''
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member that references expression_name.
    SELECT a.uuid, a.parent_uuid, a.name FROM node a
    INNER JOIN tree b ON b.parent_uuid = a.uuid
)
-- references expression name
SELECT * FROM tree;
```

And this is what I get: `Column "B.PARENT_UUID" not found`. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Besides the syntax errors, there may be a logical error with your CTE (depending on what you are trying to do).  Your current logic appears to be going up the hierarchy.  Is that what you intend to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive CTE might be slightly off.  Consider this version:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE tree (uuid, parent_uuid, name) AS (
    SELECT uuid, parent_uuid, name FROM node WHERE uuid = ''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.uuid, a.parent_uuid, a.name
    FROM node a
    INNER JOIN tree b ON b.parent_uuid = a.uuid
)

SELECT * FROM tree;
```

Comment: Could you say how can I get not only parents of the selected node, but also all siblings of the parents? Or should I ask another question?

Comment: @Shtirlits Maybe ask another question, this time use the correct syntax, and include sample data which explains what you are trying to do.

Comment: I opened a new question and gave test data with insert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68112725/how-to-get-all-parents-and-all-siblings-using-cte-for-adjacencylist-list