# How to sort parents and all siblings using CTE for adjacency list?

Tags: sql, tree, h2, common-table-expression, adjacency-list

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NODE 
(
    UUID VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PARENT_UUID VARCHAR NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (UUID)
);
```

This is my test data:

```
INSERT INTO node (uuid, parent_uuid, name)
VALUES 
('dfca05bc-551d-4e3d-87aa-7dd7d29539f6', null, 'Computers'),
('ff83eb99-ea2c-4d11-8ebe-4600445a3bda', null, 'Food'),
('405f0267-fa22-4cac-a397-c430be221828', null, 'Drinks'),
('e79ecefa-c3e2-400f-aab4-2d28fcd3a832', 'dfca05bc-551d-4e3d-87aa-7dd7d29539f6', 'Monitors'),
('61a94b77-56c2-48ff-b869-39305648a25c', 'dfca05bc-551d-4e3d-87aa-7dd7d29539f6', 'System blocks'),
('5d88a9b7-7ffe-45e5-b35f-9350072ed619', 'dfca05bc-551d-4e3d-87aa-7dd7d29539f6', 'Mother boards'),
('5994c39d-c4ea-454c-ae57-118392b93f66', 'dfca05bc-551d-4e3d-87aa-7dd7d29539f6', 'Different'),
('d1c994fe-f3ec-40ed-aace-5221c026c0ea', '5994c39d-c4ea-454c-ae57-118392b93f66', 'Keyboards'),
('7757aa9b-abee-4d30-89d3-79f77613b5e8', '5994c39d-c4ea-454c-ae57-118392b93f66', 'Mice'),
('33d93c3a-1c2d-44b9-8fac-3f83074104a5', '5994c39d-c4ea-454c-ae57-118392b93f66', 'Joysticks'),
('f13bb023-47b2-473a-83b0-4223ff6e28b9', 'e79ecefa-c3e2-400f-aab4-2d28fcd3a832', 'Size 14'),
('312a4e56-71ef-4372-a556-17ace15197e6', 'e79ecefa-c3e2-400f-aab4-2d28fcd3a832', 'Size 15'),
('c525374c-6a06-46e4-98c8-bc669e811e22', 'e79ecefa-c3e2-400f-aab4-2d28fcd3a832', 'Size 16');
```

[image]

I want to get a) all parents and their siblings b) all the siblings of the node. For example, if I have Joysticks node is selected, then I want to get

- Computers

  - Different

    - Joysticks
    - Keyboards
    - Mice
  - Monitors
  - Mother boards
  - System blocks
- Drinks
- Food

As you see Size 14, 15, 16 nodes that belong to monitors are not selected.

Up to now I have the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE theparents (uuid, parent_uuid, name, level) AS (
        SELECT uuid, parent_uuid, name, 0 AS level, 
        FROM node 
        WHERE uuid = '33d93c3a-1c2d-44b9-8fac-3f83074104a5'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT a.uuid, a.parent_uuid, a.name, b.level + 1 as level
        FROM node a
        INNER JOIN theparents b ON b.parent_uuid = a.uuid
    ),
thesiblings AS (
    SELECT a.uuid, a.parent_uuid, a.name, b.level as level
    FROM node a
    INNER JOIN theparents b ON b.parent_uuid = a.parent_uuid OR (b.parent_uuid IS NULL AND a.parent_uuid IS NULL)
)
SELECT * FROM thesiblings;
```

This query selects all nodes, but without sorting. Is it possible to sort them using sql or it can be done only manually?

Comment: You can recurse upward or downward, but not both at the same time. (unless you can nest recursive CTEs)

Answer (score 2):

You can just join the `tree` to `node`.  The only problem is to keep it sorted according to tree traversal order. Try this, tested in MySql 8.0

**EDIT**

Now sorting by names-based path, 20 is max name length in the table

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree (uuid, parent_uuid, name, level, path) AS 
(
    SELECT uuid, parent_uuid, name, 0 level, cast(Rpad(name, 20, ' ') as char(200)) path
    FROM nodes 
    WHERE uuid = '33d93c3a-1c2d-44b9-8fac-3f83074104a5'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.uuid, a.parent_uuid, a.name, level-1,  concat(Rpad(a.name, 20, ' '),'>', path)
    FROM nodes a
    INNER JOIN tree b ON b.parent_uuid = a.uuid
)
select uuid, name, level /*, path */
from (
   select n.uuid, n.name
      , max(-level) over() + level + 1  level
      , concat(substring(first_value(path) over(order by level), 1, (20+1) * (max(-level) over() + level +1 )), n.name) path
   from tree t
   join nodes n on n.parent_uuid = t.uuid 
       -- no children for starting node
       and t.level <> 0
   
   union all
   --  roots
   select uuid, name, 0, Rpad(name, 20, ' ')
   from nodes
   where parent_uuid is null 
) t
order by path
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b49f38e60ec8e8e722e24066ec7c4b79)

Comment: In my example, all siblings are sorted by name. But I don't see this sorting in your solutions. It seems that ordering is chaotic in your code. Could you explain?

Comment: You can use name-based path instead of my uuid-based path provided names are unique.  For simplicity, you can pad names to fixed length and use this length instead of length(n.uuid) in my query

Comment: Thank you very much. Very nice. If it were possible to remove "20" limit. I mean, it is better to have a more generic solution, which didn't take any name limit (that could work with any name)

Comment: You can use length of the column  from schema dictionary. Not familiar with h2 implementation, sorry.

Comment: I mean there should be any limit, not from schema dictionary, no set manually- > solution without them.